# How can execute a function in every minute in windows service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, windows-services

I want to best practise for this job.What is the best solution for run a function in every x minutes.

using a timer or thread ?

thx for your helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Timer or make use of [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/). Quartz.NET is an open source job scheduling system.

On the site there is a [Tutorial](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html), for you feature you can use a [SimpleTrigger](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_5.html).